# A binary number and the last cell

Tags: cipher

01011000010001100100010000110001001100000011010000111000001101010011011100110110

What could this mean?
Take a screenshot once you have decoded and plotted it.

Hint:

> Excel after decode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can decode it simply in

> ASCII, this gives XFD1048576

Which is

> the coordinates of the last excel cell

> [image]

Comment: Yes, fun fact: Excel spreadsheets are not infinite!